# Rest Assured - deserialize Response JSON as List<POJO>

Tags: java, json, generics, rest-assured

I have a POJO `Artwork`. I'm retrieving a `List` of those objects from a RESTful webservice in the HTTP response body in JSON format. I'm trying to write a Rest Assured-based test that would analyze the returned list. The code looks like this:

```
Response response = get("/artwork");
List returnedArtworks = response.getBody().as(List.class)
```

The problem is, I can't get Rest Assured to parse the returned JSON as `List<Artwork>`. Instead, I get a `List<LinkedHashMap>`. The map has a proper structure, i.e. could be mapped by Jackson to `Artwork` object, but I'd like to avoid mapping it manually.

JSON mappings in my model are OK, because when I map single object like this:

```
Artwork returnedArtwork = response.getBody().as(Artwork.class);
```

it works fine.

Is it possible to get `returnedArtworks` as `List<Artwork>`?

Comment: Answered your question below..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do this:

```
List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = Arrays.asList(response.getBody().as(Artwork[].class));
```

The trick is to deserialize JSON to an array of objects (because there is no difference between the JSON string of an array or a list), then convert the array to a list.

Comment: You should add an explanation to the solution for others who find this.

Comment: Thanks, I added a brief explanation (and corrected an error).

Comment: Can't check it right now, but assuming all the upvotes coming from users who found this solution useful, I'm marking this as accepted answer

Comment: I upvoted this answer, since it's concise. But it's not working for me. I've spent two hours trying to fix it, although I get this error:       `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of ................. `

Answer (score 14):

this solution works for version 3.0.2 (io.restassured):

```
  JsonPath jsonPath = RestAssured.given()
     .when()
     .get("/order")
     .then()
     .assertThat()
     .statusCode(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
     .assertThat()
     .extract().body().jsonPath();

  List<Order> orders = jsonPath.getList("", Order.class);
```

This will extract the objects for a structure like this:

```
public class Order {

private String id;

public String getId(){
return id; }

public void setId(String id){
this.id = id;
}


}
```

with the given json:

```
[ 
{ "id" : "5" }, 
{ "id" : "6" }
]
```

Comment: I get: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.util.LinkedHashMap and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Answer (score 5):

By using Google's Gson library you can easily parse it to `List<Artwork>`. Try below code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, new TypeToken<List<Artwork>>(){}.getType());

//* where jsonStr is the response string(Json) receiving from your Restful webservice
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though, it's exactly what I wanted to avoid: "The map has a proper structure, i.e. could be mapped by Jackson to Artwork object, but I'd like to avoid mapping it manually."
I was thinking if there's any chance to do it more or less like this: `List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = response.getBody().asListOf(Artwork.class)`

Comment: If your Artwork class is exactly matching with the map you are receiving from response, you can use Gson instead of Jackson. You can reuse the same Artwork class.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that much whether I use Gson or Jackson. In either case I'd have to write an additional line of code for parsing the map received in response. I hoped that Rest Assured had it implemented somehow, as it is quite often that we receive a `List` of objects in response.

Comment: `TypeToken#getType()` can be used directly as parameter in the rest-assured `.as()`. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57373937/91497

Answer (score 3):

Rest-assured provide an [`as(java.lang.reflect.Type)`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.0.0/io/restassured/response/ResponseBodyExtractionOptions.html#as-java.lang.reflect.Type-) next to the version expecting a `Class` used in the question.

```
java.lang.reflect.Type type; //TODO defines the type.
Response response = get("/artwork");
List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = response.getBody().as(type)
```

In my opinion the way the `type` variable depends from the serialization lib that is used.

---

If using Gson, as pointed out by [Purushotham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728110/91497), `TypeToken` can be used. I prefer using it directly in rest-assured:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Artwork>>(){}.getType();
Response response = get("/artwork");
List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = response.getBody().as(type)
```

---

When using Jackson, the solution is to use the `TypeFactory` ([javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html), [source](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.java)) to tell to which type it should be de-serialized:

```
Type type = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionLikeType(ArrayList.class, Artwork.class);
Response response = get("/artwork");
List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = response.getBody().as(type)
```

Answer (score 0):

With REST assured 3.0.2 you can simply check if content exists in the array

```
when().get("/artwork").then().body("artworks", hasItem("some art");
//or check multiple values in array
when().get("/artwork").then().body("artworks", hasItems("some art", "other art");
```

This way you will avoid complexity in your code by converting JSON to list more examples how to check response content can be found [link](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

Answer (score 0):

Currently we have a better solution using Typeref which will help to extract generic objects

```
List<Artwork> returnedArtworks = response.getBody().as(new TypeRef<List<Artwork>>() {});
```

or

```
response.as(new TypeRef<List<Artwork>>() {});
```